# How to determine current expansion rate of universe from observing past objects?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, physical-constants

How to determine the current expansion rate of the universe from observing past objects?
When we look into the light from objects far away, it not only very very far away in the distance it is also very further away in the past. So does this help us find the current of expansion?

Answer (score 0):

All of the space-time is summed up in the metric. In the case of our universe, under isotropic and homogenious assumptions, we get the **Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker** metric $$\mathrm{d}s^2 = \mathrm{d}t^2-a(t)^2\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{1-k r^2} + r^2 \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Omega}^2\right)$$
and when you are computing distances using this metric, you are computing them in space and time as well.

And by so, considering two objects separated by a fixed coordinate distance $\Delta \bar{l}$ the distance between them is $\Delta l = a(t)\Delta\bar{l}$. from which you can derive the Hubble law $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\Delta l}{\mathrm{d}t}=H\Delta l.$$

On the other hand, the Universe is expanding with a constant parameter $H$ in the current epoch. Therefore, wether we are measuring the expansion of past objects or present objects, we get the same information.

Comment: Wouldn't the observable universe be shrinking if space is expanding? At some point away from us, the cumulative expansion speed is faster than the speed of light and thus becomes unobservable. Or does the observable universe stay a constant size?